# How to automatically remove CSS properties on loading a page

Tags: css

There is this site, which starts flickering as soon as I visit it, removing the `margin:0;` property helps, but others are not facing this issue( They have the margin:0 property too, we use the same browsers ). Is there any way to automatically remove that property every time I visit the site?

Comment: do you own the site and have access to the source code? or is it just a site that you use but is not your site

Comment: @I_love_vegetables It's just a site I use

Comment: I'm wondering in which browser you get the issues. Does it happen in a specific browser? Or in all of your browsers? Could you provide some browser info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a browser plugin to insert the JavaScript code for the specific site. It's an easy and flexible way to run the script that you want. Sometimes I use it to remove specific parts from a website that I'm not interested in.

For example you could use the **TamperMonkey** browser plugin to do it. It's available for Chrome, Firefox Microsoft Edge, Safari, Opera Next. You can download it here: https://www.tampermonkey.net/

There's a FAQ available if you have some additional questions about how to use it:
https://www.tampermonkey.net/faq.php?ext=dhdg#Q102

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
    const bodys = document.querySelector('body');
    bodys.style.removeProperty("margin");
</script>
```

you can use the above javascript to remove margin or any other CSS property.
you have to replace body with your tag or class (.classname).

Comment: And how do I make this work every time I open the page?

Comment: he doesnt have access to the source code, so this will not work for what he is trying to achieve

Comment: in this case, you can use a console to do that. but it's not help when you refresh page or reopen it. without embedding this code into a file that's not possible with any example as @I_love_vegetables already explained to you about this.